# How to map List<Item> in POST method RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, post, request-mapping

Spring Boot 1.5.4
I need to take `List<OrderTo>` in POST method.

Controler:

```
        @PostMapping("/orderlist")
        public String confirmOrder(
                , @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) List<Integer> idL
                , @RequestParam(name = "selected", required = false) List<Integer> selectedL
                , @RequestParam(name = "typeName", required = false) List<String> typeNameL
             //   ...another Lists
             // ,@ModelAttribute List<OrderTo> notWork
        ) {
            //        Collect All Lists
```

The best option that I found is the Lists with fields of class. Maybe I'm missing something.

View:

```
<form action="orderlist" method="POST" id="catalogform">
   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
        <tr>
           <th><#--...--></th>
        </tr>
    <#list coffeetypelist as type> <#--Freemarker-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${type.id}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${type.id}" >
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="typeName" value="${type.typeName}">${type.typeName}</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="price" value="${type.price}">${type.price} TGR</td>
            <td><input type="number" size="3" name="quantity" min="0" step="1"/></td>
        </tr>
         <#--...-->
    </#list>
 <#--...-->
```

Model:

```
public class OrderTo{
 private int id;
 private  String typeName;
 private  int quantity;
 private  Double price;
 private boolean selected;
  //+constructors +getters + setters
```

Is this possible to take List without additional collecting operations? how?

Comment: You need extra  wrapper class containing `List<OrderTo>`,  and map it like `<input type="hidden" name="wrapper.orderTo[0].typeName" value="${type.typeName}">`,  just give a try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks shantaram_t for the direction of thought. The key is that we need a wrapper class.

```
public class OrderToWraper {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private List<OrderTo> items;
```

After that, valid OrderToWraper object is available from the controller:

```
@PosttMapping("/orderlist") 
public String confirmOrder(@Valid OrderToWraper orderToWraper, BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
  //...
```

There were a few non-obvious moments with list-binding using freerarker ( `<@spring.formInput>` does not work)

```
<#list orderToWraper.items as type>
 <tr>
   <td>
   <@macros.textInputHidden "orderToWraper.items[${type_index}].id"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="items[${type_index}].selected" value="true">
   </td>
   <td><@macros.textInputHidden "orderToWraper.items[${type_index}].typeName"/>${type.typeName}</td>
   <td><@macros.textInputHidden "orderToWraper.items[${type_index}].price"/>${type.price}</td>
   <td><@macros.textInput "orderToWraper.items[${type_index}].quantity" "class='form-control'"/></td>
   <td><@macros.showErrors "<br>" "text-danger"/></td>
 </tr>
</#list>
```

And freemarker macro:

```
<#macro textInputHidden path>
    <@spring.bind path/>
    <#assign id="${spring.status.expression?replace('[','')?replace(']','')}">
<input type="hidden" id="${id}" name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.stringStatusValue}">
    <#nested>
</#macro>
```